# Name of axiom that tells you that (A OR B) is NOT(NOT A AND NOT B)

Tags: boolean-logic, demorgans-law

I'm having a mental block here.

What is the name of the axiom / theorem that tells you that

```
(A OR B) == NOT(NOT A AND NOT B)
```

I'm about to review some C code and can't remember that this is called.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has little to do with programming.

Comment: @bathsheba Actually it has quite a bit too do with programming. I'm not sure why it's downvoted so much, though it doesn't show any prior research.

Comment: @P45Imminent It's OK, apologies accepted. We all have days like that, just take some rest, and don't let frustration control you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the De Morgan's law. It's usually expressed as

"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"

or

"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"